# MySQL - Pegar menor registro em uma relação 1:N

Tags: mysql, group-by, inner-join, inner

Boa noite, talvez tenha essa resposta em algum lugar mas passei o dia todo pesquisando, usando vários exemplos e nada.

Tenho 2 tabelas, uma de produtos e outra com os modelos sendo que 1 produto pode ter N modelos, cada modelo tem seu preço, então o mesmo produto pode ter N valores diferentes dependendo do modelo.

Com isso, eu preciso fazer uma busca nas 2 tabelas pegando apenas 1 produto e 1 modelo, esse modelo sendo o que tem o menor preço.
Primeiro eu fiz isso:

```
SELECT `produto`.`titulo`, `modelo`.`sku`, `modelo`.`preco_de`, `modelo`.`preco_por` FROM `produto`
INNER JOIN `modelo` ON `modelo`.`codigo_produto` = `produto`.`codigo`
ORDER BY `modelo`.`preco_por` ASC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Aqui ele pegou o produto e todos os modelos, por exemplo, uma geladeira tem 2 modelos, 110v e 220v, então listou a geladeira 2 vezes, uma com o preço da 110v e outra com o preço da 220v, com isso mudei o código para:

```
SELECT `produto`.`titulo`, `modelo`.`sku`, `modelo`.`preco_de`, `modelo`.`preco_por` FROM `produto`
INNER JOIN `modelo` ON `modelo`.`codigo_produto` = `produto`.`codigo`
GROUP BY `produto`.`codigo`
ORDER BY `modelo`.`preco_por` ASC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Blz, agora eu tenho 1 registro por produto, mas agora o ORDER BY foi ignorado porque o GROUP BY sempre pega o primeiro registro.

Preciso fazer isso para listar sempre o produto com seu modelo que tem o menor preço mas não sei mais o que fazer, já estou quase desistindo e buscando só o produto e depois fazendo 20 buscas para pegar o menor preço de cada um, para mim isso é uma derrota e não queria fazer, mas já perdi um dia todo do projeto que já está bem apertado.

Editado 01:
Usando o MIN(`modelo`.`preco_por`) AS `preco_por` indicado pelo amigo abaixo, ele realmente pega o menor preço mas continua pegando o registro que vem primeiro no banco.

Editado 02:
Estou usando MariaDB 10.5.8 que é a versão mais nova no repositório do docker.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nas três perguntas listadas no box do topo, acredito que as respostas que estão nelas vão te indicar o caminho.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia,

André, pelo que vi se você estiver utilizando o MySQL 8.0.14 ou mais recente você pode utilizar uma tabela derivada Lateral:

```
SELECT 
  produto.titulo, 
  mod.sku, 
  mod.preco_de, 
  mod.preco_por 
FROM produto,
LATERAL
(
  SELECT
    modelo.sku, 
    modelo.preco_de, 
    modelo.preco_por 
  FROM modelo
  WHERE
    modelo.codigo_produto = produto.codigo
  ORDER BY 
    modelo.preco_por ASC 
  LIMIT 1
) mod
```

**edit:** segue abaixo outra sugestão utilizando a função row_number para numerar as linhas em ordem crescente de preço

```
SELECT 
  produto.titulo, 
  mod.sku, 
  mod.preco_de, 
  mod.preco_por 
FROM produto
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT
    codigo_produto,
    sku,
    preco_de, 
    preco_por,
    row_number() over(partition by codigo_produto order by preco_por) as row_num
  FROM modelo
) mod ON mod.codigo_produto = produto.codigo
WHERE
  mod.row_num = 1
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Estou usando MariaDB, pelo que vi, implementaram isso no 10.3.x, estou no 10.1.26, na minha máquina como uso docker é fácil atualizar, vou atualizar e te retorno, se der certo, vou pedir para o pessoal da infra atualizar o servidor.

Comment: É amigo, atualizei para a 10.5.8 que é a versão mais atual do MariaDB mas pelo visto eles não implementaram ainda LATERAL.

Comment: Editei a resposta acima para acrescentar uma outra sugestão

Answer (score 0):

Você conseguirá o que deseja utilizando a função de agrupamento `MIN` juntamente com a cláusula `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT `produto`.`titulo`, MIN(`modelo`.`preco`) FROM `produto`
INNER JOIN `modelo` ON `modelo`.`codigo_produto` = `produto`.`codigo`
GROUP BY `produto`.`titulo`
```

Comment: Amigo, até pegou o menor preço, eu fiz a pergunta errada vendo agora, porque eu queria pegar o registro que tem o menor preço, tipo, ele pegou o menor preço mais o sku por exemplo, ele continuou pegando o do primeiro registro.
Vou editar minha perguntar para ficar mais claro, peço desculpa pergunta incompleta.